# Spring Boot - actuator- mappings : only own handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

is there a way in Spring Boot to display only my custom
Request Mappings with actuator? By default it shows everything.

Answer (score 3):

As described in the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-enabling-endpoints), the default behaviour of actuator endpoints, when the `actuator` module is on the classpath, is 'opt-out' - that is, most endpoints are enabled by default and must be disabled if required.

For the opposite effect (i.e. actuator endpoints must be specifically *enabled*), add the following setting to your `application.properties`:

```
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false
```

or alternatively, if using YAML:

```
management:
    endpoints:
        enabled-by-default: false
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to filter which mappings get added. [By default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html), anything with `@RequestMapping` is included.

You could always disable the provided mapping endpoint and write your own [custom endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-custom) that includes only the controllers you care about.

Comment: Thank you, built my own endpoint with the documentation 
If someone needs a copy paste:https://gist.github.com/Kaito23/4d09a6f68c57db042ba5226e97d7b716